# VB.net xml check element exist and if it has a value

Tags: xml, vb.net, xml-parsing, gettype

I have an xml ant I am trying to chcke if an element exist and if yes then if it has a value
xml example:

```
<Attributes Version="1.0.2012">  
   <OpenAtStart>True</OpenAtStart>  
   <RefreshTime>60</RefreshTime>  
 </Attributes>
```

So I want to check if OpenAtStart exists and then I want to check if it has a value :
So I built the function , below

```
Private Function existsOrEmpty(ByVal type As Type, ByVal node As XmlNode, ByVal defaultValue As Object) As Object
    Dim myObj As Object = Nothing
    Try
        Cursor.Current = Cursors.WaitCursor
        If node IsNot Nothing Then
            Select Case type
                Case GetType(Integer)
                    If Integer.TryParse(node.InnerText, myObj) = False Then
                        myObj = defaultValue
                    End If
                Case GetType(Double)
                    If Double.TryParse(node.InnerText, myObj) = False Then
                        myObj = defaultValue
                    End If
                Case GetType(Boolean)
                    If Boolean.TryParse(node.InnerText, myObj) = False Then
                        myObj = defaultValue
                    End If
                Case Else
                    myObj = node.InnerText
            End Select
        Else
            myObj = defaultValue
        End If

    Catch ex As Exception
        gError.GetAppEx(ex, CLASS_NAME & ".existsOrEmpty")
    Finally
        Cursor.Current = Cursors.Default
    End Try
    Return myObj
End Function
```

Is this a good way or there is a better/faster ?

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try `LINQ-XML` to parse XML document/string effectively.

```
 Dim str = "<Attributes Version=""1.0.2012"">" _
                   & "<OpenAtStart>True</OpenAtStart>" _
                   & "<RefreshTime>60</RefreshTime></Attributes>"

 Dim doc As XDocument = XDocument.Parse(str)
 Dim element = doc.Root.Element("OpenAtStart")

 If IsNothing(element) Then
      Console.WriteLine("Not Found")
 Else
      Console.WriteLine(element.Value)
      Console.WriteLine(element.Parent.Element("RefreshTime").Value)
 End If
```

Comment: Sorry if I missed something but the code you provide doesn't set a default value in case that is existed but empty.
So I have to make another check , if the value is null or something like that?

Comment: So I came up with this:

                                                                              
    If IsNothing(element) Then  
            Label1.Text = "Doens't exist"  
    Else
       If String.IsNullOrEmpty(element.Value) Then
                Label1.Text = defaultValue
       Else  
                Label1.Text = element.Value  
       End If  
    End If